# Docusign Completion email customize subject

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using docusign java sdk to send esignature requests with the server templates. When I send the request via API I set an email subject, which I want to change slightly when the completion email sent to the signer. Currently the same subject goes to the completion email. Can this be done in docusign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently using Branding and Subject set in API below data is populated in the Completed Email Notification - `Completed: [[Data:SubjectInput]]`, and it is done using below data node in the email resource file

```
<data name="RecipientEnvelopeComplete_Subject">
Completed: [[Data:SubjectInput]]
</data>
```

Where `[[Data:SubjectInput]]` will be replaced by the subject set using API at the time of envelope creation.

You should be able to achieve this by using Branding and customizing the Email Resource File to specify the subject for the Envelope Completion Email. You need to change details inside below nodes in the email resource file.

a. `<data name="RecipientEnvelopeComplete_HtmlBody">` for change in body of the email which will be sent to recipients of an envelope.
b. `<data name="RecipientEnvelopeComplete_PlainTextBody">` for change in body of the email which will be sent to recipients of an envelope, this node is required for non-HTML based email client.
c. `<data name="RecipientEnvelopeComplete_Subject">` for change in the subject of the email which will be sent to recipients of an envelope.
d. `<data name="SenderEnvelopeComplete_Subject">` for change in the subject of the email which will be sent to sender of an envelope.
e. `<data name="SenderEnvelopeComplete_HtmlBody">` for change in body of the email which will be sent to sender of an envelope.
f. `<data name="SenderEnvelopeComplete_PlainTextBody">` for change in body of the email which will be sent to sender of an envelope, this node is required for non-HTML based email client.

Comment: Hi Amit, Thanks for your response. Can I do String operations in the email resource? Like :Completed: [[Data:substring(SubjectInput, 10)]]. I want to show a substring of the original email subject.

Comment: String operations (like `substring`) are not supported in the email resource file.

Comment: @J4Priyan Can you please share what you are trying to achieve with an example, may be we can figure out a solution for you

Comment: I have several templates which I send envelopes with different email subjects. Ex: template 1 sub: "Tempalate 1 - Suffix" , template 2 sub: "Template 2 - Suffix". I want the completed emails subjects without the suffixes: "Template 1", "Template 2"

Comment: But why you want to change email subjects only in completed emails, ideally it should be done for all types of email notification. Since HTML does not have substring method, so DocuSign does not have such method in the resource file. If you want to have same email subjects (without suffix) in all type of email notifications, then you can do that using API by updating the subject after creating an envelope using template.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to achieve this by using [Branding](https://support.docusign.com/guides/cdse-admin-guide-branding) and customizing the [Email Resource File](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/docusign-email-resource-file-v1-1) to specify the subject for the Envelope Completion Email. At a high-level, you'd do this by doing the following:

1. Use the DocuSign web UI to login as an Admin user and create a new Brand for the account.
2. Edit the Email Resource File that's associated with the brand to specify the custom subject for the envelope completion email.
3. When sending the Envelope via the API (or, in your case, via the Java SDK), specify `brandId` within the **Create Envelope** request to specify the id of the Brand you created in step 1 (and customized in step 2).

[The answer on this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21346903/can-we-customize-the-docusign-response-email-blurbcontent-at-runtime-on-each-e) contains additional info about this procedure, and the docs I've linked to above contain info about branding and the email resource file.

Comment: Hi Kim Thank you very much for your response. I checked this and seems it is the path which I should follow. Thanks.

Comment: Happy I could help. Can you please mark this answer as an "accepted" answer so that others are more likely to benefit from the info in the future? Thanks!